# SQL Error [40001] in postgresql (dbeaver)

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

I unload the script and try to export it to a file, then an error pops up:

SQL Error [40001]: ERROR: canceling statement due to conflict with recovery
User query might have needed to see row versions that must be removed.

I don't understand what the problem is, I read similar questions, but I'm not sure it will help me, the script is heavy, but yesterday it unloaded fine, long, but it unloaded:)

Comment: Read all about it [here](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/streaming-replication-conflicts-in-postgresql/).